# Create places of closure for a necklace

Tags: wood

I need to safely make places of closure for this necklace.

The necklace has one place of closure at the neck and another one in the middle of the necklace, bottom (needs 3 places of closure).

The bottom of the closure is in wood and the other one  at the neck has wood on the bottom (1/8”) and resin on top (3/8” /16).

Velcro will not work because it’s too light and the necklace is heavy solid wood and will open up on the bottom.

- Screws won’t work because it needs to open and close as often as needed.
- I saw magnets which would be perfect but those ones may accidentally pinch the skin which would be dangerous
  https://wondertrail.com/hobby-supplies-en/magnets/macnsn0657-1-4-x-1-16-magnets-dics-by-magcraft.html
- So maybe those magnets https://www.first4magnets.com/countersunk-c41
  Could they pinch the skin accidentally?

If you think those will work (they require a screw), how do I make a hole in the wood and the resin to place the magnets? What type of tool is needed?

I have pics but don't know how to upload them on this website.

Comment: Photos will almost certainly be required for this one. Just [edit] the question and look at the toolbar at the top of the edit dialog. There are controls for adding inline photos.

Comment: Every necklace my wife owns has a "necklace clip" on it. It appears that they go by "lobster claw clasp" on the giant on-line site. You can get a bajillion of them for a few bucks. Put one at the end of a short piece of necklace chain, put the accompanying loop at the end of another piece, then attach the chain (in a permanent way) to your necklace. How to do that is left to the user, since we've been given no idea of what "this necklace" looks like.

Comment: The a closure or clasp made of wood with magnets is a fantastic idea! I wish I'd thought of it. I've had good luck with the variety of choices at [KJ Magnetics](https://www.kjmagnetics.com), these are super powerful magnets. I drill a hole matching the diameter of the magnet on my drill press, then use a tiny dab of epoxy to keep them in. If you put magnets on both sides, make sure their poles are lined up. One trick is to stick two magnets together, then use a Sharpie to put a dot on the sides that will be glued down. Nothing worse than ending up with magnets fastened to repel each other.

Comment: If you do choose to go with magnets I don't think you want any countersunk ones, since those are intended to be held in place by a small screw. I don't think pinching is enough of a potential issue to worry about with the size of magnets I'm guessing you'd have to use (because size is directly related to strength, and the small magnets you go with just won't be strong enough to give a painful nip with skin in between). And regardless of which magnet size/style you chose I promise that you'll be able to get them for far less if you order directly from China (where 99% of them are made anyway).

Answer (score -1):

Magnets are a good idea. To get the hole for them, I would say a pillar drill (for circular magnets) do mortiser (for oblong/square) would be the best way to go about it.

The concern about being pinched is also valid. I would suggest you coat it in fabric and some cushioning. This would make it softer and you are less likely to hurt yourself, plus a velvety texture on the inside would be a nice contrast to a wooden exterior.

Edit: as you (and anyone you know) may not have a pillar drill / mortiser, then power drills may be useful with the applicable radius. The biggest problen with this is it may bot be perfectly centered.

Comment: Hi, welcome to Woodworking. I'm fairly sure the OP won't have a pillar drill, much less a mortiser, given they ask in the Q "how do I make a hole in the wood and the resin to place the magnets? What type of tool is needed?" !